# Bolt CMS - List each record for taxonomy option

Tags: twig, taxonomy, bolt-cms

I'm trying to get a list of each taxonomy option, and below each of those the records which use that taxonomy option.

This is the end result I'd like:

Family/Friends/Home
        Poem 1
        Poem 2
Cath
        Poem 3
        Poem 4
        Poem 5
Politics
        Poem 6
        Poem 7

This is taxonomy.yml:

```
poems:
    name: Poems
    slug: poems
    singular_name: Poem
    singular_slug: poem
    behaves_like: categories
    options: { familyfriendshome: "Family/Friends/Home", cath: "Cath", politics: "Politics", observations: "Observations", whimsical: "Whimsical", other: "Other" }
    has_sortorder: true
```

This is contenttypes.yml

```
poems:
    name: Poems
    singular_name: poem
    behaves_like: categories
    fields:
        slug:
            type: slug
            uses: name
        name:
            label: Title of Poem
            type: text
            placeholder: e.g., The Way You Look Tonight
        sortname:
            label: Name for Sorting
            type: text
            placeholder: This won't be visible on the site - it's just for sorting
        date:
            label: Date written
            type: text
            placeholder: e.g., August 2017
        text:
            type: html
            height: 300px
            #options: 
                #ckeditor: 
                    #removeButtons: 'Format,Styles,Font,Outdent,Indent,RemoveFormat,Source'
    listing_template: poemsTEST.twig
    record_template: poemdetail.twig
    taxonomy: [ poems ]
    file_under: poems
    recordsperpage: 300
    default_status: published
```

This is what I've got so far in the listing template:

```
<ul>
    {% for poem in app.config.get('taxonomy/poems/options') %}

        <li>{{ poem }}

        {% setcontent allpoems = 'poems' where { options: 'cath' } printquery %}
            <ul>

                {% for poem in allpoems %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ poem.link }}">{{ poem.title }}</a>
                    </li>
               {% endfor %}

        </li>

            </ul>

    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is what it produces:

Family/Friends/Home
        Poem 1
        Poem 2
        Poem 3
        Poem 4
        Poem 5
        Poem 6
        Poem 7
Cath
        Poem 1
        Poem 2
        Poem 3
        Poem 4
        Poem 5
        Poem 6
        Poem 7
Politics
        Poem 1
        Poem 2
        Poem 3
        Poem 4
        Poem 5
        Poem 6
        Poem 7

I tried setting options: cath initially just to see whether it would select the correct records. If I add printquery to it, I get this:

```
SELECT bolt_poems.* FROM bolt_poems WHERE ("bolt_poems"."status" = 'published') ORDER BY datepublish DESC LIMIT 9999
```

and it lists every record and ignores the options.

Am I asking the impossible?

Thanks in advance

Cath

p.s. Something I should have noticed before. The backend Poems overview page has exactly the layout I want (with has_sortorder: true in taxonomy.yml) - the name of the taxonomy, then all the poems using that taxonomy

Answer (score 1):

In your setcontent you can use the taxonomy 'poems' directly.

```
<ul>
{% for poem_taxonomy_term in app.config.get('taxonomy/poems/options') %}
    <li>{{ poem_taxonomy_term }}
    {% setcontent allpoems = 'poems' where { poem: poem_taxonomy_term } printquery %}
        <ul>
            {% for poem_record in allpoems %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ poem_record.link }}">{{ poem_record.title }}</a>
                </li>
           {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at this, @Jadwigo, but it's giving me the same result. I get the taxonomy items, and below each one is listed every poem (regardless of which taxonomy it uses).

Comment: Ah, I could not test this on a real bolt install, so that explains why it didn't work. You have to change the setcontent line to `{% setcontent allpoems = 'poems' where { poems: poem_taxonomy_term } printquery %}` because it has to be the plural for taxonomies: https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/templating/content-fetching#using-taxonomies

Answer (score 0):

Oh joy. #3 son to the rescue. This is almost perfect - each taxonomy is listed, with only the poems that have used that taxonomy. Still to be done - if a taxonomy hasn't been used (Observations and Other), it's still appearing (with no poems below it).

```
<ul>
  {% for poem_taxonomy_term, poem_taxonomy_desc in app.config.get('taxonomy/poems/options') %}
      <li>{{ poem_taxonomy_desc }}
      {% setcontent allpoems = 'poems' %}
          <ul>
              {% for poem_record in allpoems %}
                {% if (poem_record.taxonomy['poems']['/poems/' ~ poem_taxonomy_term]) %}

                  <li>
                      <a href="{{ poem_record.link }}">{{ poem_record.title }}</a>
                  </li>
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
          </ul>
      </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

@jadwigo - is this something I should have been able to work out from the documentation?

[image]

Comment: A solution like this is not in the documentation... You need to optimize this a little bit. When you have a lot of poems it will load all poems again for each taxonomy options. If you move the line `{% setcontent allpoems = 'poems' %}` before the first `<ul>` it will only be loaded once. The check for an existing taxonomy in a record with the line `{% if (poem_record.taxonomy['poems']['/poems/' ~ poem_taxonomy_term]) %}` is very compact. If you enable `strict_variables: true` in your config.yml this line will break your site. 
For use on small sites it will probably be OK.